# From WPF Control to Silverlight Control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls

we have biuld a complex custom control for WPF. 
Now we are going to port our control to Silverlight.

Me and my collaborator, never work with silverlight! :)

Is there some best practice to follow to make a porting activity from WPF to Silverlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the next post as nice to be read: (2 parts)

[Porting from WPF to Silverlight: The Missing Pieces, Part 1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/09/21/porting-from-wpf-to-silverlight-the-missing-pieces-part-1.aspx)

[Porting from WPF to Silverlight: The Missing Pieces, Part 2](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/09/23/porting-from-wpf-to-silverlight-the-missing-pieces-part-2.aspx)

Comment: These links are so effective and practical!!

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences to be aware of, for example there are no Routed Commands in Silverlight. Maybe you want to have a look at those two links:
[Contrasting Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)
[Guidance on Differences Between WPF and Silverlight](http://wpfslguidance.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The first link is not so useful but the next rocks!